# WebDriver not available in Selenium in Android App

Tags: java, android, selenium

It seems the WebDriver and FirefoxDriver class from Selenium are not available in an Android app.  For example:

1. Downloaded Selenium's Java build. Unzipped locally.
2. Created a "lib" folder here: C:\1\Android\MyApp1\app\src\main\java\com\mycompany\lib
3. Copied *.jar files to the lib directory from the Selenium download, highlighted them all in Android Studio, right-clicked and selected "Add as Library"

Now, when I return to the main full screen activity Java class, try this import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.
```

Here, only "htmlunit" and "phantomjs" classes are available.  Why isn't "WebDriver" or "FirefoxDriver" available?  Are these not compatible with Android Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium WebDriver is used for desktop web functional automation testing. In order to be used on Android or iOS, you will need to use Appium